# Evaluate in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just wondering if its possible to convert the following to an IF statement in Javascript:

```
$('.Nav table tr:has(table.navheader) + tr:has(table.navitem)').addClass('linksbelow');
```

Example:

```
IF $('.Nav table tr:has(table.navheader) + tr:has(table.navitem)').addClass('linksbelow'); = **TRUE** (
$('.Nav table .navheader').addClass('linksbelow');
)
**ELSE** (
$('.Nav table .navheader').addClass('Nolinksbelow');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just approach it this way:

```
$('.Nav table .navheader').addClass('Nolinksbelow');
$('.Nav table tr:has(table.navheader) + tr:has(table.navitem)').addClass('linksbelow').find('.navheader').addClass('linksbelow').removeClass('Nolinksbelow');
```

Here I start by assuming that no `.navheader`s have links, then go apply the `linksbelow` class as you did before, and then (here's the important bit) **find()** the appropriate `.navheader` children and correct those by removing the (now incorrect) `Nolinksbelow` class and adding the correct `linksbelow` class.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my guess of what you could possibly want:

```
var q = $('.Nav table tr:has(table.navheader) + tr:has(table.navitem)');
if (q.length) {
    q.addClass('linksbelow');
    $('.Nav table .navheader').addClass('linksbelow');
} else {
    $('.Nav table .navheader').addClass('Nolinksbelow');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're asking, you just need the syntax for if/else in js?  [Try this](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_if_else.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You are aware that jquery *is* javascript aren't you?

Implicitly the answer to your question is therefore "yes", but you end up with a bit of javascript which feels suspiciously similar to a small part of jquery...

Comment: Yes I am aware of this, however unaware of how to achive.

Comment: I guess my question is what's the gain? Presumably you aren't allowed to use jquery?

Comment: No I can use jquery, I just dont know how? If you can shed some light i've appreciate it. Either answer above doesnt result in the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following how your first line of code relates to the "Example". Could you describe the effect you're trying to achieve in words?

Your first line reads:

> (1) Add the class `linksbelow` to all the `tr` elements that contain a `table.navitem` immediately after a `tr` that contains a `table.navheader` within `.Nav table`

And the example reads:

> (2) Add a class to any element that matches `.Nav table .navheader`. The classname is dependent on the result of (1). If the operation in (1) succeeded (presumably meaning if it matched any elements) then the classname should be `linksbelow`, otherwise `Nolinksbelow`.